# how to clear PWA cached copy on Mac chrome?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am learning PWA following the project https://github.com/gokulkrishh/demo-progressive-web-app.

When I go to: http://localhost:3000/, it shows the same page as on https://demopwa.surge.sh/

Now even when the port is not used, I think it shows a cached copy whenever I go to this url.

How can I avoid seeing be aforementioned website after opening http://localhost:3000/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed the app, enter chrome://apps/ in the address bar and right-click on the app icon and select "Remove from Chrome..."

And then make sure to clear out the browser cache

Comment: No, I didn't install app. If I do browser cache, it'll clear other website data as well right ?

Comment: Clear Browsing Data > Advanced allows you to go back for a certain period of time if you have only been testing your site recently